# Question about Fermat's little theorem

Tags: number-theory

Why is $g^e \mod p = g^{e \mod (p-1)} \mod p$ if p is prime. I don't get it. It follows from Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fermat's little theorem** $$a^p \equiv a \pmod{p} \Leftrightarrow a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}(p \nmid a)$$

so next divides $e$ with $p-1$:$$e=(p-1)r+s;$$ $$s\equiv e \pmod{p-1};$$
so we get $$g^{(p-1)r+s} \pmod {p} \equiv (g^{p-1})^rg^s \pmod{p}$$
 follow **Fermat's little theorem** $g^{p-1} \equiv 1\pmod{p}$ finally we get :$$g^{(p-1)r+s} \pmod {p} \equiv (g^{p-1})^rg^s \pmod{p} \equiv g^s \pmod{p}$$ $\Leftrightarrow$ 
$$g^e \pmod{p} \equiv g^{e \pmod{p-1}} \pmod{p}$$

Comment: @Alex For the left-to-right implication in the first equivalence to hold true, you should probably add that $p \nmid a$.